# how to play youtube (only audio) on android

Tags: android, python, audio, video, youtube

I am asking this question for the 3rd time giving the different format everytime. I will try to best explain now. 
In one sentence my question is how can i play youtube (just the audio part) in android?

the preplot of the question:
I have considered and researched several options which are
1.I can play the youtube video without showing the video.
  But for this I wont be able to use the youtube player api because they don't allow to hide the video (so rejected)
   I can play the .flv format video in youtube (that can be done) but how can I do that?

2.If not first then how can I can obtain the audio stream of the video. (Check Pafy module of python they do provide the way of doing this)

Please note that I dont want to download the video and then convert it into required format because that would be too long.
I dont want to convert the video also on the fly because that also would be too long.

Comment: _"Check Pafy module of python they do provide the way of doing this"_. It's also open source, so if they have some functionality that you're interested in you can look at how its implemented.

Comment: Yes @michael I had thought of it but I am not that sound in python It's difficult for me to decrypt it.

Comment: @therealprashant Hi, I'm searching to do something similar to what you asked for, have you found something usefull?

Comment: @Max https://github.com/prashantpandeyfun10/NewYouTubePlay